# How can you portably (x86 and AMD64) seek to a (>4GB) offset in a file?

Tags: d

How can you portably (x86 and AMD64) seek to a (>4GB) offset in a file?

File.seek() accepts a long on AMD64 and an int on x86 (or a size_t on both).

I need it to accept a long on x86.  How can I do this?

(I have horrible feeling that this is a limitation of seek in C, and that I'll have to do multiple relative seeks to get to a >4GB offset.)

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

std.stdio.File.seek takes a long but converts it to an int on Windows. That would be a limitation of Digital Mars' C runtime library. Judging by the [source code](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/stdio.d#L540), there are no other  platform limitations.

Comment: Yes, I had got myself in a mess with auto int and size_t.  It works fine.